# Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region enclosed by the curves $y=x^2 , x = 1, x = 2$, and $y=0$ about the line $x=5$

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region enclosed by the curves $y=x^2, x = 1, x = 2$, and $y=0$ about the line $x=5$.

I set up the question using the cylindrical shells method. I'm not sure if I'm setting it up correctly. I graphed out the equations but I'm not sure what the radius is. I know the height is $x^2$.

$$\int_1^2 2pi(radius?)(x^2)dx$$

Comment: Draw a picture. You will find that the radius is $5-x$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Take some nice values for $x$, say $1.3, 1.5, 1.7$. How far away are each of these from the line $x=5$? Then if I just use the value $x$, how far is it away from the line $x=5$?

Answer (score 0):

You can visualize the region and the line as follows:
[image]

You should note that, since we are on the left side of the line $x = 5$, the distance from a value $x$ to the line $x = 5$ is $5-x$. This is the radius of the shell as a function of $x$ - the distance from the axis of rotation. The height of the shell as a function of $x$ is simply $x^2$, since we are going from the $x$-axis, up to $y = x^2$. Therefore, we have

\begin{align}
V &= 2\pi \int_1^2 (5-x)x^2 \, dx \\
&= 2\pi \int_1^2 (5x^2-x^3) \, dx \\
&= 2\pi \left[\frac{5x^3}{3} - \frac{x^4}{4} \right]_1^2 \\
&= 2\pi \left[\frac{40}{3} - \frac{16}{4} - \frac{5}{3} + \frac{1}{4} \right] \\
&= 2\pi \left[\frac{35}{3} - \frac{15}{4} \right] \\
&= \pi \left[\frac{70}{3} - \frac{15}{2} \right] \\
&= \pi \left[\frac{70}{3} - \frac{15}{2} \right] \\
&= \frac{95\pi}{6}
\end{align}